# How to recover binary data lost in String encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, binary

I accidentally stored binary data I received as a String, by doing `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")`. If I do `.getBytes("UTF-8")`, I predictably don't always get the original data back.

Is that data irreparably lost or can I reverse engineer what java tried to do to make it a valid UTF-8 string and recover the data?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579403/is-there-a-way-to-recover-a-byte-array-that-represents-a-string-that-is-saved-a

Comment: The proposed duplicate question is asking about recovering the data from a different charset encoding; in this question there is no data loss due to charset encoding mismatch (as far as I understood).

Comment: true, but it still states 

> UTF-8 has quite a few byte sequences that are illegal and that will (usually) be replaced by some replacement character when decoded. When your original_bytes contained any of those byte sequences, then that information is lost for sure.